# how to find hookers to render a javascript before page onload? (css, js injection before viewing)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there tools 
auto-render step 1-4 below whenever you open a new browser page that needs custom code injection before u read.

e.g: to apply customized 
javascript or css before a page that you visit trigger onload() event;
pretty much similar with "preloader",

1.hide content container first,

2.wait for everything finish downloading

3.apply css or js on the loaded content

4.finally show up the modified content.

for example we could easily make css or javascript changes on chrome F12 console or inspector, by typing some (take javascript for eg) 
`$('img').css('visibility','hidden')` 
to hide out all images of current page.

looking for easier ways to hook such custom scripts to a browser, so that 
you don't have to manually key in and hit enter to run Custom Script when surfing through all pages you visit.

Comment: Please see if you can do the same with greasemonkey extension in FIrefox

Comment: An extension will do exactly this. Let Google answer [How to develop chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

Comment: not sure why you're using greasemonkey since you tagged chrome and chrome extension, but not firefox extension

Comment: so pity the thread is going to be closed with 1 vote and there's no need for further discussions.   @JaromandaX

Comment: why tell me, I don't care that it's off topic

Comment: well, it's simple, the first comment above recommend firefox plugin, as long as it's working i don't mind whether it's build for chrome or firefox. as I have installed both.

Answer (score 1):

- Inject styles using [stylish for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)
- inject javascript using [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

Comment: Comparing to javascript, css injection is more lightweighted, thanks for the two extensions. all tested, working fine.  but comparing "greasemonkey" and " tampermonkey",  the latter one seems to have more options in it's management panel but UI looks much ugly than the fireFox extension.

Answer (score 0):

@Shadow is the 1st come to suggested a Firefox extension:  **greasemonkey**

so I tried it out & just share config here for your reference. 
working fine.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        myscript
// @namespace   testscript
// @description hideall images
// @include     
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

$(window).load(function(){
   $('img').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

**stylish** for chrome working good and its UI is very clean and user-friendly. 
for the above example effect, css injection only need to set one line 
`img{ visibility:hidden; }`  for simple hide/show modification as such, stylish is the best tool to apply it.

inject javascript **tampermonkey** runs similar with firefox **greasemonkey**
Thanks for these recommendations.  if you want to customize more complicated injection controls, use js injector or together with css injector.